# Need example of a SSDT report for TFS 2015

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

I'm a newbie when it comes to SSDT and connecting to TFS to create reports. One of the reports that I generate twice a day is a very manual process.  I'd like to automate it or at least try. I'm having a hard time finding a step by step guide that shows how to use SSDT to connect to TFS 2015 and use WIT queries.

The example that anyone sends me can be very simple. I have some workitem queries in TFS that return the data.

One query returns all Critical 1 bugs and the other query returns High 2 bugs.

How to I use those queries to build the report in SSRS? Do I connect to the TFS_Datawarehouse or to the TFS_Analysis in the reporting server?

Comment: If you have queries that return the information you're looking for, why do you need to use the warehouse? In general, you should avoid writing your own reports against the warehouse as it is not being actively developed. The modern replacement is an OData analytics service, which unfortunately has not yet shipped in any on-prem versions of TFS. In any case, the reports that ship with TFS should give you a good starting point for any custom reports you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean custom reports with SSRS, then you can reference below samples:

- [Using Custom Reports in TFS: Part 3 – How to set up my reporting
  environment and structure](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/03/13/using-custom-reports-in-tfs-part-3-how-to-set-up-my-reporting-environment-and-structure/)
- [TFS Reports using SSRS](http://tech.lds.org/wiki/TFS_Reports_using_SSRS#Creating_New_Reports_in_SSRS)

More information about the TFS report you can refer to below links:

- [Create and manage Reporting Services reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/create-and-manage-reporting-services-reports?view=tfs-2018)
- [Add reports to a team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/add-reports-to-a-team-project?toc=%2Fvsts%2Freport%2Fsql-reports%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fvsts%2Freport%2Fsql-reports%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018)
- [How To: Create a Custom Report for Visual Studio Team Foundation
  Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668978.aspx)
- [Creating and Customizing TFS Reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx)

Comment: @Pat Delaney Have you resolved the issue? any update?